# Is there a way to install insync on elementary OS?

Tags: software-installation

There doesn't seem to be an installer offered on the website and I couldn't find any terminal instructions either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do supply a client [Downloads Insync](https://www.insynchq.com/downloads). Click on the orange Download for Linux button, select Ubuntu 18.04 64bit and click on the Download button. After the download completes, use [Eddy](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.eddy/) to open the downloaded file and install Insync.

You can launch it from the Applications menu.

Comment: I've already given up on Elementary (keyboard stopped working on login screen)
But I will mark this as the correct answer, since it rings true to me.